# Doing different parallel operations on each item emitted by an Observable

Tags: rx-java

Consider the following sample

```
        Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> integerSubscriber) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                    integerSubscriber.onNext(i);

                }
                integerSubscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        }).parallel(new Func1<Observable<Integer>, Observable<Result>>() {

            @Override
            public Observable<Result> call(Observable<Integer> integerObservable) {
               return integerObservable.flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<Result>>() {

                   @Override
                   public Observable<Result> call(final Integer i) {
                       Result r = new Result();

                       r.i = i;
                       r.iSquare = i * i;
                       r.iQube = i * i * i;

                       return Observable.just(r);
                   }

               });
            }
        }).subscribe(new Observer<Result> () {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                System.out.println("Done.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Result r) {
                System.out.println(r.i + ", " + r.iSquare + ", " + r.iQube);
            }

        });
```

This would take each integer on a parallel thread evaluate the square and cube of it. But the process of squaring and cubing is done one after the other and done by the same thread. What is the best way to do the squaring and cubing also on parallel threads?

So the section of code that is currently

```
@Override
public Observable<Result> call(Observable<Integer> integerObservable) {
   return integerObservable.flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<Result>>() {

       @Override
       public Observable<Result> call(final Integer i) {
           Result r = new Result();

           r.i = i;
           r.iSquare = i * i;
           r.iQube = i * i * i;

           return Observable.just(r);
       }

   });
}
```

would become

```
public Observable<Result> call(Observable<Integer> integerObservable) {
   return integerObservable.flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<Result>>() {



                   @Override
                   public Observable<Result> call(final Integer i) {
                       Result r = new Result();

                       r.i = i;
                       r.iSquare = doOnParallelThread(i * i);
                       r.iQube = doOnParallelThread(i * i * i);



                       return Observable.just(r);
                   }

               });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution that I came up with based on kjones solution below.

```
final List<Result> results = new ArrayList<>();

Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {

    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> integerSubscriber) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            integerSubscriber.onNext(i);

        }
        integerSubscriber.onCompleted();
    }
})
.parallel(new Func1<Observable<Integer>, Observable<Result>>() {

    @Override
    public Observable<Result> call(Observable<Integer> integerObservable) {
        return integerObservable.flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<Result>>() {

            @Override
            public Observable<Result> call(Integer i) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " processing " + i);
                return Observable.zip(
                        Observable.just(i),
                        Observable.just(i)
                                .map(new Func1<Integer, Integer> () {

                                      @Override
                                      public Integer call(Integer i) {
                                          System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " squaring " + i);
                                          sleep();
                                          return i * i;
                                      }
                                })
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()),
                        Observable.just(i)
                                .map(new Func1<Integer, Integer> () {

                                      @Override
                                      public Integer call(Integer i) {
                                          System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " qubing " + i);
                                          sleep();
                                          return i * i * i;
                                      }

                                })
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()),
                        Observable.just(i)
                                .map(new Func1<Integer, Integer> () {

                                      @Override
                                      public Integer call(Integer i) {
                                          System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " 4th power " + i);
                                          sleep();
                                          return i * i * i * i;
                                      }

                                })
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()),
                        new Func4<Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Result> () {

                            @Override
                            public Result call(Integer i, Integer square, Integer qube, Integer fourth) {
                                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " combining results " + i + ", " + square + ", " + qube + ", " + fourth);
                                return new Result(i,  square, qube, fourth);
                            }

                        });
            }

        });
    }

})
.subscribe(new Observer<Result>() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " computed " + results);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Result r) {
        results.add(r);
    }

});
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```java
Observable
        .range(1, 10)
        .parallel(new Func1<Observable<Integer>, Observable<Result>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Result> call(Observable<Integer> parallelIntegerObservable) {
                final Observable<Integer> integerObservable =
                        parallelIntegerObservable
                                .cache();

                // Zip runs in parallel but subscribes serially to each subscriber. Use
                // the subscribeOn() method to force each calculation to run async. If
                // iSquare & iQube were long running or blocking operations then there
                // is probably no need to use the subscribeOn() method call below.
                return Observable.zip(
                        integerObservable,
                        integerObservable
                                .map(new Func1<Integer, Integer>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public Integer call(Integer i) {
                                        return i * i;
                                    }
                                }),
                        integerObservable
                                .map(new Func1<Integer, Integer>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public Integer call(Integer i) {
                                        return i * i * i;
                                    }
                                }),
                        new Func3<Integer, Integer, Integer, Result>() {
                            @Override
                            public Result call(Integer i, Integer iSquare, Integer iQube) {
                                return new Result(i, iSquare, iQube);
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .subscribe(
                // Your same logic here.
        );
```

**EDIT:** It appears that the integerObservable created by the .parallel operator can only be subscribed to once (RxJava 0.20.0). I've modified the code above to cache the integer emitted by that observable so that it only has one subscriber. The following code is the modified code:

```java
public Observable<Result> call(Observable<Integer> parallelIntegerObservable) {
    final Observable<Integer> integerObservable =
            parallelIntegerObservable
                    .cache();
```

Comment: The integerObservable seems to have stopped emitting values after the cubes were computed.

Comment: @GirishKolanthra - It appears that the integerObservable created by the .parallel operator can only be subscribed to once (RxJava 0.20.0). See edit for a solution.

Comment: This seems to work but I noticed that the square and cube are calculated on the same thread, even after I added subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()) to the observables passed into the zip